# First order logic - position of quantifier

Tags: logic, logical-operators, predicate, first-order-logic

When you have a statement with →, does it matter if you use a quantifier before or after the implication?

ex. the statement "Every man loves a king" (2 different semantic interpretations)

1. Every man loves a king and these kings may all differ from each other. `∀x IsMan(x) → ∃y (IsKing(y) ∧ Loves(x,y))`
2. There is a single king that every man loves. `∃y, ∀x (IsKing(y) ∧ IsMan(x)) → Loves(x,y)`

For #1, would it be equally correct to write it as `∀x, ∃y, (IsMan(x) ∧ IsKing(y)) → Loves(x,y)`?

And for #2, what about `∃y IsKing(y) → ∀x (IsMan(x) ∧ Loves(x,y))`?

Comment: The quantifier needs to appear to the left of all free variable to which it applies. If it doesnt the quantifier doesnt bound the variable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the order of quantifier matters to decide the satisfiability/validity of a formula.

One way to be sure of it is to know that `(A → B)` is the same as `(not A or B)` and that `(not (∀x x))`is the same as `(∃x (not x))`.

Thus, when you have `(∃x, ∀y x → y)` it is the same as `(∀x ∃y ((not x) or y))`.

Which is different from `(∃x, x → ∀y y)` which can then be `((∀x (not x) or (∀y y))`.